# Create concatenated column of row-wise unique values across columns

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:8,
f1 = c("A","B","B","C","C","C","A","A"),
f2 = c("A",NA,"B",NA,"B","A","B","A"),
f3 = c("A",NA,NA,NA,NA,"A","C","C"))
```

What I would like to create is a column that contains the unique values present in each row (NAs excluded).  So the result would be the column "f_values":

```
  id f1   f2   f3 f_values
1  1  A    A    A        A
2  2  B <NA> <NA>        B
3  3  B    B <NA>        B
4  4  C <NA> <NA>        C
5  5  C    B <NA>       CB
6  6  C    A    A       CA
7  7  A    B    C      ABC
8  8  A    A    C       AC
```

row1 is A b/c only A appears.  row6 is CA because C and A appear uniquely.  I'd describe the function as paste row-wise unique.  I'm aware that it will be possible chain together a number of comparison operators and paste statements, but the real data has many more columns so I was hoping someone knew an easier way.

Comment: Note that you have two different `df`s shown in the question

Answer (score 2):

Given `df` above,

```
f_values<- sapply(apply(df[,-1],1, unique),function(x) paste(na.omit(x),collapse = ""))
df_new<-cbind(df,f_values)
```

`df_new` will be the desired outcome as formulated in your question.

Comment: You could do it all in `apply()` and not have to use two loops. `apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) paste0(na.omit(unique(x)), collapse = ""))`

Comment: If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll select it as the correct one.  It's definitely the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this in `data.table` by grouping with 'id'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, f_values := paste(na.omit(unique(unlist(.SD))), collapse="") , id]
```